Wagtail_Modeltranslation for MultiFieldPanel
i had problem related to translating fields inside MultiFieldPanel...when i tried to translate fields i can not show it on admin.But outside MultiFieldPanel it works fine like FieldPanel("body") and also i tried to understand the docs but not working also link:https://wagtail-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced%20settings.html
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("header_title"),
                FieldPanel("header_subtitle"),
                FieldPanel("header_image"),
                FieldPanel("intro", classname="full"),
                FieldPanel("body"),
                FieldPanel("wide_content"),
            ],
            heading="Article",
            classname="collapsible collapsed",
        ),
    ]

translations.py:
class ProjectPageTR(TranslationOptions):
    fields = (
        "hero_title",
        "hero_subtitle",
        "header_title",
        "header_subtitle",
        "intro",
        "body",
        "wide_content",
    )

